# JQuery Post in a php loop works not perfect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have following list.php that creates a list with items and a button (Erledigt!) that send a Jquery Post to wishdelete2.php. The problem is that the JQuery post works not perfect: One time I need to press the button 3x or 5x and than the Jquery processed. But I want that I only need 1x and the Jquery post is processed. What must I change?

list.php:

```
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Wünsche</title>
<!-- <script src="../jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
table{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 
}
table th{
    padding:5px; 
    border:#5f5f5f 1px solid;

}
table td{
    padding:5px; 
    border:#5f5f5f 1px solid;
}
table tr{
    background: #bbbbbb;
}
table tr:nth-child(4n){
    background: #e3e3e3;
}
</style>

</head>
<div id="resulter"></div>
<body>
<h3>Wünsche</h3>
<table>
<tr><th>Zeit</th><th>IMDB-ID</th><th></th><th></th><th>Counter</th><th>Titel</th><th>Art</th></tr>
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=********;dbname=********;charset=utf8', '********', '********');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ******** WHERE not marker = 'oU' ORDER BY cast(counter as int) DESC, timestamp ";
foreach($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
$id = $row['id'];
$timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
$counter = $row['counter'];
$art = $row['art'];
$imdbid = $row['imdb_id'];

$title = $row['title'];
$language = $row['language'];
$aufloesung = $row['aufloesung'];
$marker = $row['marker'];
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $timestamp ?></td><td><?php echo $imdbid ?></td><td><?php echo $language ?></td>
<td><?php echo $aufloesung ?></td><td class="counter"><?php echo $counter ?></td><td class="title" style=""><?php echo $title ?></td><td><?php echo $art ?></td><td><?php echo $marker ?></td>
<td style="padding:0;"><button class="<?php echo $id ?>">Erledigt!</button>
<select class="marker<?php echo $id ?>"><option></option><option>oD</option><option>oDwE</option><option>wE</option><option>oE</option><option>oU</option></select></td></tr>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".<?php echo $id ?>").click(function(){
        var id = "<?php echo $id ?>",
        marker =  $(".marker<?php echo $id ?>").val();
        $.post("wishdelete2.php", 
            { id:  id,
            marker: marker
            });
        location.reload();
    });
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

and wishdelete2.php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("********","********","********","********");
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
$marker = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['marker']);
mysqli_close($con);

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=********;dbname=********;charset=utf8', '********', '********');
if(empty($marker)){
$stmt = $pdo->query("DELETE FROM ******** WHERE id='$id' ");
}else{
$stmt = $pdo->query("UPDATE ******** SET marker='$marker', IP='' WHERE id='$id' ");
}
?>
```

Comment: Well the post request is going to take a little bit of time, are you sure you're not just pressing the button while it's already processing the request?

Comment: Check your browser's debugging tools.  When you press the button the first time, does your click handler execute?  Is the AJAX request made?  Be specific about how this is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery.post` is an asynchronous function, i.e. the request will not have been sent once this function returns. The problem is that you call `location.reload()` right after calling `post`, so in most cases your request will not have been sent before your browser has reloaded the page. If you want to reload the page after the post request has been sent, pass a handler to `post`, e.g. to the `success` event.

As explained in [the documentation of `jQuery.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), you can simply pass a function after your data, like so:

```js
$.post(
    "wishdelete2.php", 
    {id: id, marker: marker},
    function () { location.reload(); }
);
```

Note that this handler is a `success` handler and thus will only be called, if the post request succeeds. You may want to have a look at the linked documentation and provide an error handler to inform the user of a failure, if necessary.

Also, you should think of adding some indication that the page is waiting for the post request. You can google for *loading spinners* to find the commonly used animated graphics indicating that there's a script loading something in the background. Of course displaying such a spinner is only one way of indicating this. Be creative.